# Node / Javascript Set Date Time

Tags: javascript

I have parameters startTime and endTime which are in the format of:

```
var time1 = "08:00";
var time2 = "23:00";
```

I need to compare whether the current date/time is in between these two periods:

```
var now = new Date();

if (now > time1 && now < time2)
{
console.log("We are in the time period");
}
```

It is impossible to change the input of time1 or time2.

I was thinking abotu converting time1 and time2 to a new Date format, however I am unsure how to go about this.

How would you go about it?

Thanks

Comment: Why the downvote? Happy to fix but let me know what is wrong...

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if "current time" is between 2 times. But also check for nights as the day before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954510/check-if-current-time-is-between-2-times-but-also-check-for-nights-as-the-day)

Comment: I understand that you want to compare hours in the current day right?

Comment: @Del - yes, essentially I need to convert 08:00 to todays date at 08:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
var time1 = parseInt("08:00".substring(0,2)); 
var time2 = parseInt("23:00".substring(0,2)); 


var now = new Date();

if (now > new Date().setHours(time1) && now < new Date().setHours(time2))
{
console.log("We are in the time period");
}
```